# uploading a txt file using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I am having problems uploading a data file to a server. On the objective-c side everything seems to be working (I enabled a progress bar which slowly increases to 100%). Here is the code (you can assume uploadURL is the correct URL and outFilePath is the correct path to the file "out.txt", I have doubled checked this):

```
ASIFormDataRequest *uploadRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:uploadURL];
[uploadRequest setUploadProgressDelegate:uploadProgress];
[uploadRequest setFile:outFilePath forKey:@"file"];
[uploadRequest startSynchronous];
```

The server does not seem to be receiving the data file. Here is the php code (which I did not write):

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]$
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
?>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what does the script say? does it echo an error code? does it echo anything at all?

Comment: @pkyeck: The variable uploadURL is equal to http://buildmac.ee.pitt.edu/~wsn/boinclite/upload_file. I believe you can use that link to see what it echos.

Answer (score 2):

if i run this code (taken from ASIHTTP examples)

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://buildmac.ee.pitt.edu/~wsn/boinclite/upload_file"];

[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"value1"];
[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"value2"];
[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"value3"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:20];

//Create a 256KB file
NSData *data = [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:256*1024] autorelease];
NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:NO];

[request setFile:path forKey:@"file"];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

i get this as a result (using Charles Proxy to monitor the upload):

```
Upload: file
Type: application/octet-stream
Size: 256 Kb
Temp file: /private/var/tmp/phpi6UDp1
Stored in: upload/file
```

so everything is running as it should.

Comment: I've been able to get your code to work but something is still going wrong with mine. I copied and pasted your code into mine and then edited the necessary values. Everything was working until I changed the path for the file to upload.. Could there be something about my data file that is restricting it from being uploaded?

Comment: It seems as though when I add text to the file being uploaded, it no longer works. I opened the blank file you create in your code and then added the word "hi" to it and tried to upload that and got the same kind of error I am getting with my data file.

Comment: Using the charles proxy: the response I am getting is "Return Code: 1<br />".

Comment: that means that the file you're trying to upload exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE (http://de3.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thank you very much!